# Error when loading RandomGraphs script

Tags: netlogo

When I try and load some NetLogo scripts (not all), among which the included RandomGraphs.nlogo, I get an error:

Nothing named NW:SET-SNAPSHOT has been defined.

Any clue? I am running the latest version of NetLogo (5.1.0) on Ubuntu 14.04 and OpenJDK.

Comment: The latest version of NetLogo is 5.1.0, not 5.0.1.

Comment: I mispelled that! I am editing the question.

Answer (score 3):

NetLogo is trying to find the `nw` extension, i.e. the Networks extension.  This comes bundled with NetLogo 5.1.0, which you can download from the [main NetLogo site](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/).  I don't believe that NetLogo 5.0.1 comes with the Networks extension included, although you can install the old version of the extension from the [NetLogo extensions page](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions). (I have 5.0.4 installed as well as 5.1.0, and 5.0.4 doesn't include the Networks extension, so I assume that 5.0.1 doesn't have it.)

(To help you understand what's generating the error message, is this is the NetLogo model you're loading: https://github.com/danfrancis/sna/blob/master/RandomGraphs.nlogo?  You'll see at the top of the file that it asks for the `nw` extension with the command `extensions [nw]`, and then later uses the extension's commands with the syntax `nw:<commandname>`.)

Comment: This is absolutely correct. The NW-extension started being bundled in 5.1.0. That version will not work with previous versions of NetLogo. Also, nw no longer uses snapshots but uses contexts instead, so the script Dario mentions will have to be changed. See https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#general

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I mispelled the version of NetLogo I am using: it is actually the 5.1.0, and the script does not work. I received another suggestion: to comment with `;` the line of code calling for `nw`, and the script is now working.